# Rails: Update all but the most recently created for each in a has many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two classes:

```
class Account
  has_many :follow_ups
end

class FollowUp
  belongs_to :account
end
```

For every account, I need to introduce a `completed_at` column on `FollowUp`. I also need to do the following for each account: set `completed_at` to Jan., 1, 1900 for every follow-up except the most recently created follow-up.

I tried putting the following in a single migration file, but it left all `FollowUp`s' `completed_at` as `nil`.

```
class AddCompletedAtToFollowUps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :follow_ups, :completed_at, :datetime

    set_all_but_most_recent_follow_ups_as_long_completed_for_each_account
  end

  private

  def set_all_but_most_recent_follow_ups_as_long_completed_for_each_account
    Account.all.each do |account|
      all_but_most_recent_follow_up_for(account).find_each do |follow_up|
        follow_up.update(completed_at: Time.utc(1900))
      end
    end
  end

  def all_but_most_recent_follow_up_for(account)
    account.follow_ups.order(created_at: :desc).offset(1)
  end
end
```

I know this is a horrible O(n^2) setup, but what I'm surprised about is that it doesn't even work.

Can anybody help me divine the fastest query to accomplish this?

P.S.  `all_but_most_recent_follow_up_for(account).update_all` updated *all* of the `FollowUps`, which is also incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work well enough. (But I do suspect there's something more efficient, perhaps something that avoids iteration.)

```
class AddCompletedAtToFollowUps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :follow_ups, :completed_at, :datetime

    set_all_but_most_recent_follow_ups_as_long_completed_for_each_account
  end

  private

  def set_all_but_most_recent_follow_ups_as_long_completed_for_each_account
    Account.all.find_each do |account|
      follow_ups = account.follow_ups
      count = follow_ups.count

      next unless count > 1

      follow_ups.order(created_at: :asc).limit(count - 1).
        update_all(completed_at: Time.utc(1900))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a lot of SQL you could use an `OFFSET` clause:

```
class AddCompletedAtToFollowUps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :follow_ups, :completed_at, :datetime
    Account.find_each do |a| 
      FollowUp.update_all("completed_at = '#{Time.utc(1900)}' where id in (select id from follow_ups where account_id = #{a.id} order by created_at desc offset 1)")
    end
  end
end
```